# How do I run npm start when it shows following error?

Tags: reactjs, npm

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\sourcecode\my-app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\sourcecode\my-app\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-08-27T21_55_22_405Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Seems like you are in the wrong path, you need to run npm start on that path where your package.json is.

Answer (score 0):

So when it show an error like this it very easy to tackle this problem.
You simply need to know the folder inside which your src,public,package.json,
package-lock.json,README.md files are present in this case that folder is
my-app.
So, now you know the folder which is my-app in this case you simply go to the terminal
and do "cd foldername" in this case it is "cd my-app" and then "npm start".
then your live server will open properly.